# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification Image pricing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, price

I am integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to users that have my mobile application installed.
I have a question regarding the actual price of sending a push notification with an image, although FCM is supposed to be free if you want to send an image with your push notification on the Firebase console it says that you either need a valid HTTPS URL or to set up a Blaze Plan and use storage.
Assuming that with storage they mean Cloud Storage which is free until a quota, why is the Blaze plan needed?
Also, what operations/services will I be paying for each notification? Do I have to pay the "download operation" fee for every notification I send? Or the "GB downloaded" fee? Or both?
If going the other route, utilizing a valid HTTPS URL, I would still need to host the image somewhere, within Firebase how could I do this, and at what cost?

I am hoping someone can shed some light on this, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Firebase Storage for hosting the images, you pay for the bandwidth and operations that are consumed when a device retrieves the image. The pricing for Cloud Storage is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), and typically consists of a small part for the operation itself and then a (bigger) part for the bandwidth.

Say you have a 50KB image in each notification message, and you send 100 messages per month and 1,000 devices retrieve each image, that'd use 50Kb * 100 * 1,000 = 0.5GB in bandwidth, which would be around $0.06 in bandwidth cost.

Of course 0.5GB is well within the free tier, so you'd actually not pay anything. But if you've used up your free tier on Cloud Storage, you'd end up paying that amount for the bandwidth in this example.

Note that Firebase Cloud Messaging itself is still completely free, and the cost is purely for hosting/serving the images from Cloud Storage. If you were to use a different host for the images, you could still pay nothing for Google Cloud overall.